# Passing parameters between controllers Devise Ruby on Rails

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

In order to book a course the user has to first sign up. I then want the user to get redirected to the course page they were on before the sign up form.

I'm trying to pass the course_id through params and I can see them added to the params when on the sign up form page but I cannot get the param to be added to the path in the controller.

Any ideas please? The code below has the course_id forced in as number 6 and this works. I just need to have this integer as a variable passed in by the params.

Devise Controller with the redirect after user sign up

```
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
#       user_path(resource)
        new_booking_path(course_id: 6)
    end
```

Course Show Page (Brings user to devise sign up page if not already logged in. I've added the course_id from the param)

```
<%= link_to "BOOK NOW", new_user_registration_path(course_id: @course.id),  class: "ice-btn light-btn dark-btn" %>
```

So from here i need to pass this param into the sign up form so that the course_id in the controller has the correct variable added. Should i add a hidden field in the devise form containing the variable?

Devise sign up form

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 forms card">
<div class="form-header">
<h2>In order to book a course we just need some details from you so that you can login at a later stage to view the courses you have enrolled on.</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="form-inner">
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/devisemessage' %>

   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "First Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :fname %>
  </div><br />

   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Surname" %>
    <%= f.text_field :lname %>
  </div><br />

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div><br />

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div><br />

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div><br />

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button "Proceed to Booking page", class: "ice-btn light-btn dark-btn" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Devise has you covered on this.

> [Devise redirect to a page after signin](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

Basically you need to define `after_sign_in_path_for`

Comment: Thanks David however I've followed these directions and even though I got the redirect error first time around when I followed the instructions to prevent that it just redirects back to the root page after user signs up. I have noticed that this looks like its only for when a user signs in and not signs up guessing from the after_sign_up_path_for(resource) method says rooth_path but I did try see would it redirect me back to previous page after I signed in but again just sent me back to root_path.

Comment: The method above does work and will bring a user who signs up back to course with id 6. I just need to figure out how to store this course id in a session as a user presses the book now button on the course page. This book now button does launch the sign up form. I'm thinking a modal might be an easier way and better user experience for the user option.